# Constructing associative containers

Tags: c++, stl, constructor, containers, associative

I was convinced (until I just tried it a moment ago) that it was possible to instantiate an associative container with array style notation.

For example,

```
std::set< int > _set = { 2, 3, 5 };
```

This isn't the case but I am wondering if there is any other way of bulk initialising a container in the constructor like this?

Comment: That should be possible in C++0x. As the language is currently, you can't initialize any container with this syntax.

Comment: Is `std::set` really an associative container?

Comment: @FredOverflow: According to the [sgi documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html) it is a sorted associative container.

Comment: @FredOverflow: what's your doubt?

Comment: @Arun: I always thought that an associative container provides a mapping from keys to elements, such as `std::map<K, V>` (each key is *associated* with its value).

Comment: @Fred: I see now. You expected some "association" between two values. In C++ standard library (and originally STL), `map`, `multimap`, `set`, `multiset` are called associative containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Boost.Assign](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

```
std::set< int > _set = boost::assign::list_of(2)(3)(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
const int x[] = { 2, 3, 5 };
std::set<int> _set(&x[0], &x[sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])]);
```

!